# How can I show only the names of this data I took from my database?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have created this table with information I have in my database, but now I have to make a select box with values so I can show only the names for example. Should I use if statements to do so?

```
<?php
try {
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=snm', "root", "");
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = "SELECT ID,Voornaam,Achternaam,Woonplaats,Postcode,Email,Social,Soort,Categoriebord,Categoriegame FROM gebruiker";
    print "<table>";
    $result = $con->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print " <tr>";
    foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
        print " <th>$field</th>";
    }
    print " </tr> ";
    $data = $con->query($query);
    $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        print " <tr> ";
        foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
            print " <td>$value</td> ";
        }
        print " </tr> ";
    }
    print "</table> ";

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not just `SELECT` the columns you need instead of so many of them? (and maybe the `id` field for reference)

Answer (score 0):

I have made some modifications on your code, I've added couple of methods which will get you the attributes and attributes with values separately

This method will return values with attributes

```
function getValues($con, $query)
{
....
}
```

This method will get you only the attributes

```
function getKeys($con, $query)
{
...
}
```

It'll return the attributes like below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ID
    [1] => Voornaam
    [2] => Achternaam
    [3] => Woonplaats
    [4] => Postcode
    [5] => Email
    [6] => Social
    [7] => Soort
    [8] => Categoriebord
    [9] => Categoriegame
)
```

you can display the attributes with index like `<option value="$row[0]">$row[0]</option>` for attribute `ID`

I hope this will help you, just replace your code with this

```
function getKeys($con, $query)
{
    $result = $con->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return array_keys($row); // This will fetch the keys from an array
}

function getValues($con, $query)
{
    $data = $con->query($query);
    $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $data;
}

try {
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=snm', "root", "");
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = "SELECT ID,Voornaam,Achternaam,Woonplaats,Postcode,Email,Social,Soort,Categoriebord,Categoriegame FROM gebruiker";

    //Select Box
    $data = getKeys($con, $query);
    print '<select>';
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        print " <option value='".$row[0]."'>".$row[0]."</option>"; // ID
        print " <option value='".$row[1]."'>".$row[1]."</option>"; // Voornaam
        print " <option value='".$row[2]."'>".$row[2]."</option>"; // Achternaam
    }
    print '</select>';


    //Title
    print "<table>";
    $array_keys = getKeys($con, $query);

    print " <tr>";
    foreach ($array_keys as $value) {
        print " <th>$value</th>";
    }
    print " </tr> ";

    //Values
    $data = getValues($con, $query);
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        print " <tr> ";
        foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
            print " <td>$value</td> ";
        }
        print " </tr> ";
    }
    print "</table> ";

} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

Comment: but if i wanted to select for example "ID" in the select box, and only the ID should be displayed, how would i do that?

Comment: @J_K I've updated my answer with explanation, please check it.